JPA + Hibernate count query for pagination fails when using fetches
I have 3 entities, lets' call them Parent, Child1 and Child2. Parent has a @OneToOne relationship with the other two:
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "child1", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Child1 child1;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "child2", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Child2 child2;

Queries are performed using JpaSpecificationExecutor and passing both Specification and Pageable objects. Both the relationships are specified to be fetched by the Specification, so the generated SQL looke something like this:
select <a lot of fields from p, c1, c2>
from parent p
join child1 c1 <on something>
join child2 c2 <on something>
order by <some timestamp field>
limit M offset N

Issue appears when there are more results than a single page can hold, so JPA has to perform a count query. And the way that SimpleJpaRepository does that is by simply applying the same specification that you gave it to that new count query.
This leads to an exception:
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [SqmSingularJoin(Parent(332551168492391).child1(332551168541736) : child1)]]

Which I guess makes sense, since the generated query would look something like this:
select count(*)
from parent p
join child1 c1 <on something>
join child2 c2 <on something>
order by <some timestamp field>

That is, we join the tables but don't actually select anything from them.
So what would be the best way to proceed from here?

Once I changed the title a bit, more of similar questions popped up and I stumbled upon this answer. Since I don't have access to countQuery from JPQL, this seemed to be the best solution. However, I modified it to be less brittle:
        if (Parent.class.isAssignableFrom(query.getResultType())) {
            root.fetch("child1");
            root.fetch("child1");
        } else {
            root.join("child2");
            root.join("child2");
        }

This seems to work nicely, and the joins are even omitted from the count query. Just don't forget to include any possible projections into the check, if you use any.
